# Python logger.yaml use two different loggers to log to two different files

Tags: python, logging

I am using python logger module. My objective is to have two different loggers that each log to different log files, with the same loglevel (I chose which file to log which messages)

Currently my `logger.yml` file is the following:

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: WARNING
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    filename: logs/applog.log
    maxBytes: 5242880
    backupCount: 3
  file2:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    filename: logs/applog2.log
    maxBytes: 5242880
    backupCount: 2
loggers:
  logger1:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console, file]
    propagate: no
    additivity: no
  logger2:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file2]
    propagate: no
```

On my code, I can initialize both, and both log files are created. Messages to log file `applog.log` are added correctly but nothing is added to the second log file `applog2.log`

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

# Main interactive program loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Initialize logging
    with open('app/logger.yaml', 'r') as f:
        config_d = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config_d)
    logger = logging.getLogger('logger1')  
    secondary_logger = logging.getLogger('logger2')
    logger.info('APP has started')
    secondary_logger.debug('This is the secondary log')
    
    #Rest of the code omitted...
```

I am not sure how to manage to call and reference both loggers that are created in the `.yml` config file.

Comment: Additional info: If I do `secondary_logger.hasHandlers()` after setting `propagate` to `yes` on both loggers I get `True`. But if afterwards I print the results from `secondary_logger.handlers` I get an empty array `[]` indicating the logger does not have any handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the code I found out I had a typo in the second logger definition where I was using `handles` instead of `handler` after changing it to the correct value, both loggers exist and log to their respective files.

Oddly enough, `logging.config.dictConfig()` did not complain of an incorrect config value.

Comment: You're allowed to have other things in a logging config dictionary - the logging system doesn't do strict checking against a schema.